# Show phone numbers in CNContactViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactviewcontroller

Is it possible to make CNContactViewController show the contacts' phone numbers along with their names? I looked it up but couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CNContactViewController is native view controller. You cannot change any thing in it. What you can do is to access all the contacts from contact book along with their phone numbers and show it in your own table view controller